# Cannot add Judopay to Xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin, reference, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to include Judopay in my project, and I was able to add it to Android and iOS, but not to the Xamarin forms project. There is no NuGet to be included and I can't seem to add the component reference. Any idea on how can I add it? I cannot use any of these:

```
using JudoDotNetXamarin;
using JudoPayDotNet.Enums;
using JudoPayDotNet.Models;
```

Again, they only work on iOS or Android, but not Xam forms.

Comment: You will probably have to wrap the platform specific stuff and use dependency injection to get it to work with forms.

Comment: All I had to do was adding the components folder manually to my project and then edit my references. They didn't appear at first, but then I was able to unclude the folder and finally I just added the references to my .csproj file

Comment: These are the references (in case it helps someone):

<Reference Include="JudoDotNetXamarin">
      <HintPath>..\..\Components\judopay-xamarin-sdk-3.0.4\lib\android\JudoDotNetXamarin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="JudoDotNetXamarinAndroidSDK">
      <HintPath>..\..\Components\judopay-xamarin-sdk-3.0.4\lib\android\JudoDotNetXamarinAndroidSDK.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="JudoDotNetXamariniOSSDK">
      <HintPath>..\..\Components\judopay-xamarin-sdk-3.0.4\lib\ios-unified\JudoDotNetXamariniOSSDK.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

Answer (score 0):

That is because they only provide platform implementations. You will need to tell your Forms app which implementation to use at what time.

The correct way to go about this is with some form of [IoC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx), using dependency injection or service location. Luckily Xamarin Forms has this integrated:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/

Using the references from the Android or iOS projects in your shared code will likely not work completely or break things. Maybe not immediately but surely later on. (Except when there really is no platform-specific functionality, then you might get away with this.)